# Mechanical bike disc brake caliper lever

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers, brake-pads

Where can I find a data sheet for this part? I want to know if there is a magnification factor between the force which acts on the disc brake by pads, and the force that I pull the wire with, as I want to pull the wire with a servo motor. I calculated the force that pads should act on the disc brake, and I want to know the force with which I should pull the wire with the servo motor. Subsequently I can know the suitable torque of the servo motor I can buy to do this this job correctly.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a copy of the Avid BB5, but I suggest you measure everything you need.  It's just a lever so the normal mechanical advantage calculations apply - for a given cable pull, the pad moves less.  Work out the ratio and you have your answer (note, it's not perfectly linear, but close enough not to matter)

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32835156343.html  looks like you could buy several for under $100 and do some destructive testing.  Good luck !

Comment: Magnification effect will be closely proportional to the ratio of cable pull length vs pad displacement distance.

Answer (score 2):

The leverage curve that an individual caliper provides will never be published, but if you have the brake, you have the information. Take the pads out, poke a cable through so that the head is sitting in the housing stop, run it through so that the it's passing by the anchor but not clamped, and then use a fine tip marker to put on 1mm tick marks. Use a locking plier or similar to clamp it at each successive tick mark, and for each one use a vernier to measure the distance between the pistons. Graph that and you have your answer.

The data you're looking for is always a curve, never a ratio, because the anchor is not moving in a straight line towards the housing stop.